# How to implement Ethereum protocol to some tinyOS, e.g, contiki?

Tags: wallets, cpp-ethereum, iot, embedded

I find out Ethereum has many implements to many OS with many different languages.

But i don't know if I want to use ethereum as protocol on contiki OS or cooja simulation, so what is the best choice for my case? (with C language).
And How can install Ethereum on Contiki as protocol? And i can call it as an API.
Here, Contiki is a kind of tinyOS(http://www.contiki-os.org/).

Please help me fix this issue.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3):

At a minimium you'd need to implement a light client - a complete copy of the blockchain clearly isn't going to be practical here. But even a light client has to do a lot of work - cryptographic hashing and VM execution - and is unlikely to be practical on a constrained device.

A better approach yet would be to have the client on a separate, more powerful node that you trust, and simply call that node from your constrained device to do work for it. This is already possible at present, by using the JSON APIs exposed by all the current Ethereum clients.

Comment: How can i create a light client node? Could I use C APIs because contiki already support C language? If you have any link to download documents, source,... please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @phuong There currently aren't any true light clients, so you'd be breaking new ground - but I still think that, for a constrained device, you'd be better off making it rely on an external node on a more powerful one.

Comment: I asked that because I see the same result from samsung & IBM. They integrated Ethereum to Sensor network, with some tinyOS. But I don't really find how to do that with coonja simulation. If you know how to do, please help me or give me your advise

Comment: @phuong I haven't looked, but I'd be extremely surprised if they're running Ethereum on sensor nodes; they'll be running a lightweight RPC protocol on them, talking to a full node elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, They deployed Ethererium on tablet and their specific machine. But they give a conclusion that they can apply ethereum for IOT (it means they can use it for communicate purpose between sensors). You can review it youtube: https://www.youtube.com
/watch?v=U1XOPIqyP7A. 
I also check and find out that we can you this version of ethereum for android: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Ethereum-on-Android.
But I still not know that how can I deploy C version of ethereum for Contiki OS and integrate with cooja simulation.
Please help me & give me some advise. Thank a lot

Comment: An Android device is a whole lot less constrained than the average Android device; for a start, you need several gigabytes of storage. I don't see any indication in the video that they're running the actual Ethereum node on the constrained device itself. You're not simply going to be able to cross-compile an Ethereum client for Contiki.

Comment: If i just use Ethereum with a private network, I think I don't need to download several GB to storage. I just need to generate a private network which can use Blockchain technique. I think it's enough.

Comment: True, but then you can't interact with the public network, and you need separate devices that do the mining anyway - so why not make them the gateways, too?

Comment: I just want to do some trial first. In real, I have gateways for global. So I just need to integrate contiki & ethereum first.

Comment: All I can suggest is what I've been suggesting all along: Don't try and run Ethereum on contiki, make RPC calls from your Contiki device to a full node elsewhere.